# Passive of "talk about"?

Tags: passive-voice

- They are talking about her.

Assuming we have this sentence that needs to be made passive, what do we get?

My variant is:

- She is being talked about.

But I'm guessing this isn't right and there is no passive for "**talk about**".

Comment: This is called a 'prepositional passive', permitted when the oblique (the object of the preposition) is affected by the action of the verb.

Comment: @StoneyB So assuming we have some other **prepositional phrase**, can we use it in a similar way?

Comment: Folks, [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) are not for chit-chat or sharing of personal information. If you want to chat, [get a chat room](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms). @NicholasCastagnola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"She's being talked about" is a valid, well-attested prepositional passive construction of "they are talking about her".

Not all prepositional phrases can be used this way, however. As @StoneyB said, the complement of the preposition usually needs to have a semantic role of *Affected*—it must be affected by the action denoted by the verb. Otherwise, it's not possible:

> <sup>?</sup>*Boston was arrived in by him*—unidiomatic

Note that Preposition Stranding is obligatory in this construction, so it's usually avoided in formal writing.